# Django why raising Permission denied when saving a FileField?

Tags: django

I have a Django app root at `/var/project` and a model defined as this:

```
class Notice(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=80, default='', blank=True) 
    info = models.FileField("info", null=True, upload_to='app/files') 

class NoticeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Notice
        fields = ('title', 'info')
```

When saving `info` fields, it always raise error like:

```
Internal Server Error: /app/notice/update/9

PermissionError at /app/notice/update/9
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/project/media/app/files/bm.py'
```

I think the permission settings are O.K. because:

a) I run the Django app via uwsgi via `www-data` user like this:

```
    [uwsgi]
    uid = www-data
    gid = www-data
    chmod-socket = 666
    chown-socket = www-data:www-data
```

b) the media folder:

```
(www)root@iZ94x23urx9Z:/var/project/media/app# ls -l
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 36864 Jul 19 20:03 avatar
drw-rw-rw- 2 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 19 15:06 files
```

c) the nginx static conf:

```
location /media  {
    alias /var/project/media;
}
location /static {
    alias /var/project/static;
}
```

d) I've another model which has a field `tx = models.ImageField("tx",blank=True, null=True,upload_to='app/avatar')`  and all are OK when saving this field.

This problem bothers me a whole day. What on earth is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/19333/276810), and problem solved. I don't know why but it just works.

```
 chgrp -R www-data /var/project
 chmod -R g+w /var/project
 usermod -a -G www-data root
 find /var/project -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
 find /var/project -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} \;
```